# input in a function and remove lines from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

I'm trying to make a modules and for one of the commands I need it to remove a specified user. I need help with it finding the line the user is at. Then deleting the username. Here is the code.

```
def delete_usr(usr):
    file = open("Username.txt","r+")
    count = 0
    userfound = False
    try:
        for user in file.readlines():
            count += 1
            if usr == user.strip():
                userfound = True
```

BTW i also need it to delete the password. The password has the same line as the username and is kept in password.txt

Answer (score 1):

The closest solution to your suggestion would be:

```
def delete_usr(usr):
    file = open("Username.txt","r+")
    count = 0
    userfound = False
    for user in file.readlines():
        #print(user.strip())
        count += 1
        if usr == user.strip():
            userfound = True
            #print("yeah")
            #break 
    file.close()
```

If you use a try statement, you expect a perticular kind of error (eg. key not in a dictionary) and also should write except statement to catch the error. 
If you use open(file), it is a good practice to also use file.close(). If you use the with statement, as in the example above, you don't need to do it as it is done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (as long as the user is only on a single line, else remove the `break` statement):

```
def delete_usr(usr):

    with open("Username.txt","r") as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()
        for idx, l in enumerate(lines):
            if usr==l.split(':')[0]:
                lines[idx] = ''
                break
    with open("Username.txt","w") as myfile:
        [myfile.write(i) for i in lines]
```

Comment: what part of the code records the line  the username was at. I need it to delete the password because the username and the password have the same line

Comment: Why are you using `usr in l.strip()`? This will delete other users whose names include the desired user as a substring.

Comment: @UnknownHamster The line number is in `idx`.

Comment: @UnknownHamster Why do you have usernames and passwords in different files? Why not a single file with something like `username:password`, then you don't have to keep the files in sync?

Comment: @UnknownHamster `idx` indicates the location of the matching user inside of the list `lines`. @Barmar thank you for pointing that out, I have updated my answer to account for your example `username:password` format